# Where do I find what SQLAnywhere ASA6532 Error Is Tellling Me?

Tags: sqlanywhere

I am trying to do an insert into a micros sql anywhere table (not created by me) and am getting this error

`ERROR [23000] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Constraint 'ASA6532' violated: Invalid value in table 'emp_def'`

I can't find where the contraints on the table are defined nore am I able to figure out what this error is trying to tell me.

I have googled without any success - I have tried pulling the values off the insert one-by-one without success.

Could someone point me to where I might find what this error is trying to tell me?

Also, could someone tell me where to find custom-defined column types?

Comment: I found my specific error - a column is defined as int and a 8-digit value was being added which would seem to fit but did not - the error message from SQLAnywhere was terrible and did not tell me this, however

Comment: Yo should add your comment as an answer, and mark it has accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found my specific error - a column is defined as int and a 8-digit value was being added which would seem to fit but did not - the error message from SQLAnywhere was terrible and did not tell me this, however.  And I never did find the right page to translate the error codes properly